# Simple Gif like animation with Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I can't really find a simple solution for this, every example I see only shows very complex solutions, but all I want is 2-3 images that cycle so it appears as if it is animated. Same effect as an animated Gif.  For now I have this to create an image

```
MonsterNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MonsterNode_GameScene")
```

but how would I set MonsterNode variable to an animation of this sort? I am really looking for the very least amount of code needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea is to use `animateWithTextures` for this task. You need to set all the frames that the sprite needs to animated and the displayed time of each frame. Then use `repeatActionForever` to run the animation loop.

```
// Add 3 frames
let f0 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "MonsterNode_GameScene_0")
let f1 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "MonsterNode_GameScene_1")
let f2 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "MonsterNode_GameScene_2")
let frames: [SKTexture] = [f0, f1, f2]

// Load the first frame as initialization
monsterNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MonsterNode_GameScene_0")
monsterNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

// Change the frame per 0.2 sec
let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame: 0.2)
monsterNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation))

self.addChild(monsterNode)
```

Comment: I tried this but my sprites look like a big red X now.

Comment: // Scale your images to the desired size you want this will reduce it by half as an example. monsterNode.xScale = .5 monsterNode.yScale = .5

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue of big red X.
So instead of defining the monsterNode in code. I created the monstor on sks screen by dragging first image of animation from atlas folder. Then assign it a name: monsterNode from properties section. Here's the code

```
var runAnimation = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let runAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "run")
    for index in 1...runAtlas.textureNames.count{
        let textureName = String.init(format: "run%1d", index)
        runAnimation.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: textureName))
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let monsterNode = self.childNode(withName: "monsterNode")
    if(monsterNode != nil){
        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: runAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        monsterNode?.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animation))
     }       
}
```