# ARKit – How to load a GIF animation in ARSession?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, ios11, arkit

I am working on an application using ARKit and SceneKit frameworks.  I am able to render my 3D object, create overlay etc. I want to load a GIF animation like a overlay in `ARSession` on tap of one of my child nodes. Is this possible?

I tried adding `SKScene` as a overlay to my `SCNScene` like below, and it looks good.

```
informationOverlay = InformationOverlayScene(size: self.sceneView.frame.size)
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene = informationOverlay
```

But how to load this GIF file in `SKScene` or `SCNNode`?

Comment: Isn't the point of augmented reality to have everything in 3D, not 2D?

Comment: @ LinusGeffarth Yes i am loading 3D model only. But there is a requirement that i need to show an animated gif like an overlay playing on top of my 3D model.

Comment: *"on top of my 3D model"* as in "mapped onto the surface" or as in "somewhere on the screen"?

Comment: If i tap childnode A, i should be displaying it some space above childnode A

Comment: It is mapped onto the surface

Comment: No Linus, augmented reality is certainly not exclusively for 3D. In fact, XCode includes templates for both ARKit+SceneKit and ARKit+SpriteKit. Besides augmenting reality with 2D graphics, it’s not uncommon to combine both 2D and 3D in augmented reality applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SO question answers how to display an animation inside an `SKNode`:
[Simple Gif like animation with Spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338706/simple-gif-like-animation-with-spritekit)

You could use projectPoint to project the location of the `SCNNode` (of your 3D model) to a 2D location on screen, and then use that for the location of the `SKNode` containing the animation. That way the animation will always face the screen.

Alternatively, you could assign a Core Animation layer containing the animation to the `.diffuse.contents` property of a `SCNMaterial` and assign that to a `SCNPlane` which you can add to the scene and position above the 3D model. If you want that plane to face the camera, simply assign the `.pointOfView.orientantion` property of your `SCNView` to the `SCNNode` that holds the `SCNPlane`.

Comment: How to add SKNode that contains the gif animation to ARSCNView.scene?

Comment: I tried adding it to CALayer and then to SCNNode with diffuse.contents and it is working!! But my gif image is only showing in half :( How to show full gif image in SCNNode? I tried changing the bounds value of CALayer  and SCNPlane's width and height but no effect. Only SCNPlane size increases and still my gif animation is showing in half.